# Returning Words Within a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, return

I created a method to output a String.  Using the split method and a for loop, I added each word in my sentence into a String array, replacxing the last two letters of each word with "ed".  Now, my return statement should return each of the words.  When I used System.out.print, it worked.  When I use a return and call it in my main method, I get this output: "[Ljava.lang.String;@1b6235b"

The error seems so simple but I just don't know where I'm going worng.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my method:

```
public String[] processInfo() {

    String sentence = this.phrase;
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    if (!this.phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("Fred")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = words[i].substring(0, words[i].length() - 2).concat(
                    "ed ");

            // System.out.print(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return words;

}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(processInfo())`

Comment: A good idea however, it returns my Strings in an Array format. My aim is to return them back into sentence format. So for example, if my input is, "Hey my name is Fred", it would output as, "Hed ed naed ed Fred". Sorry, I forgot to add that it also seperates it with commas when using Arrays.toString.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing arrays but arrays don't have a proper implementation of `toString()` method by default.
What you see is

> "[Ljava.lang.String;@1b6235b"

This is `[Ljava.lang.String;` is the name for String[].class, the java.lang.Class representing the class of array of String followed by its hashCode. 
In order to print the array you should use [Arrays.toString(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

> A good idea however, it returns my Strings in an Array format. My aim
>   is to return them back into sentence format. So for example, if my
>   input is, "Hey my name is Fred", it would output as, "Hed ed naed ed
>   Fred". Sorry, I forgot to add that it also seperates it with commas
>   when using Arrays.toString

Then you should modify your processInfo() returning a String or creating a new method that convert your `String[]` to a String.

Example :

```
//you use like this
String [] processInfoArray = processInfo();
System.out.println(myToString(processInfoArray));

// and in another part you code something like this 
public static String myToString(String[] array){
       if(array == null || array.length == 0)
            return ""; 

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
         sb.append(array[i]).append(" ");
       }
       return sb.append(array[array.length -1]).toString();
}
```

Comment: Plus for string builder.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can get from your question and comment is that your aim is to return them back into sentence format. So for example, if your input is, "Hey my name is Fred", it would output as, "Hed ed naed ed Fred".

In that case you should return a String, and not an array. I have modified your method a bit to do so. Let me know if you wanted something else.

```
public String processInfo() {

    String sentence = this.phrase;
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    if (!this.phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("Fred")) {
        sentence = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = words[i].substring(0, words[i].length() - 2).concat(
                    "ed ");
            sentence += " " + words[i];
            // System.out.print(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return sentence.trim();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out call to System.out.print is printing each element of the array from inside the loop.  Your method is returning a String[].  When you try to print an array, you will get the java representation of the array as you are seeing.  You either need to change your method to build and return a string with all the array entries concatenated together, or your calling code needs to loop through the returned array and print each entry.